# Composition of injective functions

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

I have the following statement to prove but I have no idea how to do so. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Let $f: A \to B$ and $g: B \to A$ be two functions such that $g \circ f (x) = x$ for all $x \in A$. Show that $f$ is injective and $f \circ g(y) = y$ for all $y \in f(A)$.

Comment: what has been tried ? what about cardinality of the sets are they infinite or not ?

Comment: @Bernard those are the two functions I have but I am not sure if they want me to do a generalized proof or not.

Comment: To prove f is injective, assume f(x) = f(y).  Now get with it and finish the proof.

Comment: @Bernard I thin the second assertion is OK, because it asserts $f\circ g(y)=y$ for all $y\in f(A)$, not for all $y\in B$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass: Oh yes! It seems I read too  hastily the O. P.'s question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f$ is injective because if $f(y) = f(x)$ then $x =g(f(x)) = g(f(y))=y$

Now for the second assertion if $y\in f(A)$ this means there's an $x$ such that $y=f(x)$. Now we have $f(g(y)) = f(g(f(x)) = f(x) = y$.

Comment: When you talk about the injective part, I am confused with how you get from f(y) = f(x) to x = g(f(x))

Comment: @MichelleDrolet That's because $g\circ f(x) = g(f(x)) = x$. This means that $g(f(y))=y$ too and since we assume that $f(x)=g(x)$ then it follows that $x=y$ from that.

Comment: perfect thank you very much!!